# linphone 'make' error: Could not find ndk-build, Could not find android

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, android-ndk, linphone

I've followed multiple solutions, but still have no resolution. This is what I have...

Linphone residing in eclipse project root directory:

```
:~/workspace/David2/linphone-android$
```

my `.bashrc` is as follows:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c
```

My android-sdk is in directory according to paths, same goes for the NDK..

The following is what I run in my Linphone dir...

```
~/workspace/David2/linphone-android$ sudo make
Could not find ndk-build. Please install android NDK.
Could not find android. Please install android SDK.
```

Running Dual boot with: `"Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"`

Linphone: `sudo git clone git://git.linphone.org/linphone-android.git –recursive`

Directory to show where SDK/NDK are located

`~/Desktop/android$ dir
android-ndk-r10c           android-sdk-linux`

I have no idea why it is not recognizing paths.. Only thing I could think of is that `export PATH=${PATH}:` is in wrong format...

Eclipse is set to corresponding paths also...

[Eclipse NDK Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPz2M.png)

[Eclipse SDK Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0BVz.png)

Comment: Also tried to use this for my .bashrc:

 `export SDK_PATH=/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux

export NDK_PATH=/home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c`

Comment: Try this way: `export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c`

Comment: also check what are you getting while running command `echo $PATH`

Comment: @activesince93 `~/workspace/David2/linphone-android$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools::/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/tools:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:/home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c
`

Comment: Some times we need to set these paths in `Makefile` also. In the project folder.

Comment: @activesince93 Same issue. I am guessing the way you wanted me to try is all one line correct? If that is the case, it did not seem to affect it.

Comment: @activesince93 Okay, I will check the Makefile and see what it has to say...

Comment: When I tried it `overrides`the old path. So I did this way and it worked for me.

Comment: @activesince93 I see that towards the top of the makefile, I get: `NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname which ndk-build)` in addition to `SDK_PATH=$(shell dirname which android)` & `SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS_PATH=$(shell dirname which adb)`

Comment: @activesince93 I am guessing override it as `NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname /home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c)` ?

Comment: Yes, I have read this somewhere. Hope this helps.

Comment: @activesince93 definitely, I will look more into this. Thanks!

Comment: Do not know why it still is not working. I have my Makefile from `# NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname which ndk-build)`  TO  `NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname /home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c)`

Comment: Have you tried same for `SDK_PATH` and `SDK_TOOLS_PATH`?

Comment: @activesince93 Yes. `NDK_PATH=$(shell dirname /home/david/Desktop/android/android-ndk-r10c)

SDK_PATH=$(shell dirname /home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux)

SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS_PATH=$(shell dirname /home/david/Desktop/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools)`

Comment: the NDK/SDK project paths are referring to the downloaded NDK/SDK folders correct?

Comment: I will try again tomorrow...

Comment: Issue still persists. I started over following the tutorial located at `http://www.coders-hub.com/2015/04/start-working-on-linphone-android-part-1.html#.Vk4-1|WDGko` 

any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have succeeded with `$ make`

- NDK **must** be `10c`  (

> EDIT - Built successfully with `NDK 10e`

- SDK can be `latest android sdk`

**1.** Put all folders (including `linphone-android` in `/home` directory

**2.** `.bashrc` set is as follows:

```
     export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/android-sdk-linux/tools
     export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
     export PATH=${PATH}:/home/david/android-ndk-r10c

                  (Download `android-ndk-r10c` from Google)
```

**3.** Next, change permissions on `check_tools.sh` located in `linphone` root directory.

**4.** `chown -R user:user check_tools.sh` -- replace user with your user/group etc...

Since I have dual boot + Windows/Ubuntu, I did this:

```
  `$ vi check_tools` --> add `set fileformat=dos` to top of file
```

or `set fileformat=unix` depending on your system to top of file...

**5.** Revert `owner` of `check_tools.sh` back to `root:root`

**6.** Open up new terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T` and type `sudo apt-get install liblwp-protocol-https-perl` -- Otherwise you will get a https error..

**7.** Finally, open up new terminal `Ctrl+Alt+T`, go to `linphone-android` root.. type `make`

```
 > `$ sudo make` displayed errors, but `$ make` seemed to work fine...
```

**8.** Leave `makefile` alone, did no changes to it...

Hopefully this helps anyone out who is experiencing "like" issues...

Thanks for the help!